# How to figure out kind of link and seperate / make single?

Tags: objects, linked-data

I have an old blend model which is obviously made of some base parts which are used multiple times. The used parts seem to be some kind of linked objects but i can't figure out which.

Why do i want to find out? I want to remove the bottom (green) parts here
[image: before]

but when i do, it removes all parts in the scene
[image: after]

I would like to remove this link and make all local/single.

Also tried the  `U > Unlink Object+Data` attempt - dosen't get better. Also exported as obj file and reimported, but links persist.

Perhaps the curved arrow icon (first image red circle) could be a hint what kind of link this is (and how to unlink).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be that you don't use the **object data**, for this keyboard shortcut to be useful. Then using group duplication use function **Make Duplicates Real** instead (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)